# QGIS orthographic projection problem

Tags: qgis, coordinate-system

I'm trying to change the CRS of a Natural Earth raster file (NE2_HR_LC_SR_W_DR.tif) to an orthographic projection centered near the North pole. Here's the proj string I used:

+proj=ortho +lat_0=80.5 +lon_0=36

But I get this weird result:

[image]

Any ideas on how to fix this?

Comment: Сould you provide a link to download the raster, please. Maybe upload this raster to cloud storage and write a download link here. And what version of QGIS is installed on your computer? It is important for bug reporting.

Comment: Here's the file link: https://www.naturalearthdata.com/http//www.naturalearthdata.com/download/10m/raster/NE2_HR_LC_SR_W_DR.zip

Comment: I'm using QGIS 3.22 on a Mac. My computer is too old to run the latest QGIS version.

Comment: Thank you so much - I really appreciate it.

Answer (score 3):

```
+proj=ortho +f=0 +lat_0=80.5 +lon_0=36 +x_0=0 +y_0=0 +datum=WGS84 +units=m +no_defs
```

[image]

[image]